# How to place tab bar on top of screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I m pretty new to objective -C and  have stumbled upon this issue ..

I have to have a tab bar on top of screen and some buttons like search ,Info,Profile on it .If a button is pressed then correspondingly it should open its own view.But I found that in iPhone tab bar is placed at bottom. How can I place tab bar on top of screen.? If not possible then what could be the alternative to achieve my task .

Any help is appreciable...

Comment: I found it helpful so i have upvote it

Answer (score 3):

i think what you searching is here.
https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController

Comment: I have downloaded the project but could not run it bcoz it is giving error "Xcode cannot run using the selected device.No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."How to get rid of it ?

Comment: @07405 check out your Xcode version, it may be that it's not up-to-date or your iOS device has iOS version that is not supported by Xcode. Or it well may be that you didn't install provisioning profiles for your device. Go to Organizer - Devices to do this.

Comment: @07405, you can run this app in simulator also ,just change the target to simulator instead of iOS device from toolbar.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative to your task is placing it at the bottom. It's against the [iOS User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW52) to place it anywhere else.

Comment: K I got it that tab bar can be placed only at bottom.Could u please tell me what elz (any other control) to achieve my task?

Comment: Why doesn't a tab bar at the bottom of the screen do the job?

Comment: Why? iOS users are used to tab bars at the bottom, so putting it (or something similar) at the top will confuse them, which is not a good user experience.

Comment: Maybe a Navigation controller would be what he is looking for. (Yeah I get that this was from last year)