# How can we place tab bar on top of screen in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have usually placed tab bar on its as usual bottom I have used following code in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` for that.

```
    MemberVC *MemberTabBar = [[MemberVC alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navMember =   [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:MemberTabBar];
    MemberTabBar.tabBarItem.title = @"Member";

    MemberTabBar.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_icon.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    MemberTabBar.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_icon.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    -----------------------
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
      self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navMember,navEvent,navPromo,navProfile,navAbout];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

I haver found one source to place it in top but i want to find out the better way.
I have gained some knowledge about how to place in top from following git projects. If any one knows some better way then i will be glad to know about that
https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController

[How to place tab bar on top of screen in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13054636/how-to-place-tab-bar-on-top-of-screen-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move the TabBar to the top. You'll have to create custom one. Check this article about customizing tab bar:

http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

Basing on it you may move the custom tab bar to the top and acheive desired result

Comment: i will check that and reply you

Answer (score 0):

One way is, you can add `UIViewController` instead of `UITabBarController` and add a tabBar to that view controller on the top.

[This link](https://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/ios-dev-add-tabbar-to-a-view-without-a-tabbarcontroller/) may help you.

Comment: i will check that and reply you